# Multiple level of interfaces - Returning pointer to base interface

Tags: c++, interface

In C++ is it safe/OK to have multiple levels of interface, but only return pointers to the base one and then cast it later on?

Example:

```
class ILight
{
    virtual vec3 Colour() = 0;
    virtual void Colour(vec3 colour) = 0;
};

class ISpotlight : public ILight
{
    virtual vec3 Position() = 0;
}
```

I implement ISpotlight in Spot. In a factory I have a function:

```
ILight *CreateSpot()
{
    return new Spot();
}
```

If I want to use it later I can `static_cast<Spot>`.  The reason is that I can then have different types of lights.

Comment: What advantages do you get by setting `ILight*` instead of `ISpotLight*` as return type if your function always return a `ISpotLight*`?

Comment: `ILight` needs a virtual destructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In C++ is it safe/OK to have multiple levels of interface, but only return the base one and then cast it later on?

Yes.

> if I want to use it later I can static_cast.

I would recommend not using `static_cast`. I recommend using `dynamic_cast`, check whether the cast was successful, and use the pointer only if `dynamic_cast` was successful.

Answer (score 0):

> but only return pointers to the base one and then cast it later on?

This is an indication of a design error in all but a few scenarios (a cache of named objects, for example).